# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog Problems

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to work with jasperreports and I have the next mistake when I try to run an application I'm developing:

```
        org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at es.uniway.principal.EnviarInfoPedido.infoPedido_Mayorista(EnviarInfoPedido.java:452)
    at es.uniway.principal.ObtenerProcesos.ejecutar(ObtenerProcesos.java:78)

    at es.uniway.principal.SincronizadorCloud.main(SincronizadorCloud.java:14)
```

For the code I have this I'm writing:

```
    xtw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter(nombre_report+".xml"));

            //
           // xmlwriter.WriteStartDocument();

            xtw.writeStartDocument();

            // nodo 1
            xtw.writeStartElement("request");
            xtw.writeAttribute("operationName", "runReport");
            xtw.writeAttribute("locale", "es");
            // nodo 2
            xtw.writeStartElement("argument");
            xtw.writeAttribute("name","RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT");
            xtw.writeCharacters(formato.trim().toUpperCase());
            xtw.writeEndElement();  // nodo 2
            // nodo 2
            xtw.writeStartElement("argument");
            xtw.writeAttribute("name","USE_DIME_ATTACHMENTS");
            xtw.writeCharacters("1");
            xtw.writeEndElement();  // nodo 2
            // nodo 3
            xtw.writeStartElement("resourceDescriptor");
            xtw.writeAttribute("name","");
            xtw.writeAttribute("wsType","");
            xtw.writeAttribute("uriString", CARPETA_REPORT + nombre_report.trim());
            xtw.writeAttribute("isNew", "false");

            //// nodo 4
            //xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("label", null);
            //xmlwriter.WriteEndElement(); // nodo 4  

            if (nombre_report == "LINEAS_DETALLE_COSTE" && id_albaran_coste.trim() != " ")
            {
                // para las lÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â­neas detalle coste teneos 2 parÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¡metros:
                //   - NALNARANC --> albaran para calcular el descuento de coste
                //   - NALBARANV --> albaran para calcular el descuento de venta
                // parametro 1
                xtw.writeStartElement("parameter");
                xtw.writeAttribute("name", "NALBARANC");
                xtw.writeAttribute("class", "java.lang.Integer");
                xtw.writeCharacters(id_albaran_coste);
                xtw.writeEndElement(); // parametro 1

                // parametro 2
                xtw.writeStartElement("parameter");
                xtw.writeAttribute("name", "NALBARANV");
                xtw.writeAttribute("class", "java.lang.Integer");
                xtw.writeCharacters(id_albaran);
                xtw.writeEndElement(); // parametro 1
            }
            else
            {
                // parametro 1
                xtw.writeStartElement("parameter");
                xtw.writeAttribute("name", "NALBARAN");
                xtw.writeAttribute("class", "java.lang.Integer");
                xtw.writeCharacters(id_albaran);
                xtw.writeEndElement(); // parametro 1
            }



            xtw.writeEndDocument();
            xtw.flush();
            xtw.close();
```

What is wrong?. Thanks. The xml is this and I don't know what is wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> <request operationName="runReport" locale="es"> <argument name="RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT"> CSV </argument> <argument name="USE_DIME_ATTACHMENTS"> 1</argument><resourceDescriptor name="" wsType="" uriString="/ICLDI/CABECERA_PEDIDO_CONTRATO" isNew="false"><parameter name="NALBARAN" class="java.lang.Integer">6658</parameter></resourceDescriptor></request>
```

Thanks once again.

Comment: You code writes XML, but you show an exception of a XML parser. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: When I try to work with reportStubcloud.runReport(sb.toString()); it fails and I don't know why

Comment: runReport is a method form the JasperReport API and this method needs a String.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Could you show the API? Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> <request
```

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><request
```

Other problems may be that you have some invisible extra character on the very beginning of the XML file, for example Byte-Order-Mark (also known as BOM) It shows that a UTF-16 file is high-endian or low-endian.

Comment: How can I see if there is a BOM?. Thanks

Comment: Open the file with hex editor (e.g. in `mc` on Linux), then you can see `FE FF` or `FF FE` as the first 2 bytes - that's BOM. Anyway, it's good to have a closer look to the problem.